# How to include the default color for ArrayPlot ColorRules to the SwatchLegend?

Tags: color, legending

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];
a = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 10];
colors = {1 -> Red, 2 -> Blue, 3 -> Green, _ -> Black};
ArrayPlot[{a}
 , ColorRules -> colors
 , PlotLegends -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image]

It is possible to create the legend manually. Is there a built-in way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayPlot[{a}, ColorRules -> colors, 
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Values@colors, Keys@colors]]
```

[image]

You can also use

```
PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend @@ Reverse[Transpose[List @@@ colors]]
```

Comment: `ColorRules` are read and implemented as soon as encountered. Swapping `_` with `3` messes the colors (although the legend stays correct), which I think should not be the case.

Comment: I think this should be expected because rules specified by `ColorRules` are, most likely, used with `Replace` or `ReplaceAll` and _**"ReplaceAll looks at each part of expr, tries all the rules on it, and then goes on to the next part of expr. The first rule that applies to a particular part is used; no further rules are tried on that part or on any of its subparts. "**_

Comment: ... That is,  rules specified after `_->..` are effectively ignored. So `_->..` should be the last rule in `colors`; if not, we can use `SortBy[First]@colors`.

Comment: I think the use of `Values` and `Keys` raises hopes just a little, but since `Replace*` has been around since before `Association`, it is understandable that it was used. Thanks for the explanation.